# How to calculate the repulsive strength (weight) of a magnet given gap between the magnet and a base?

Tags: magnetic-fields

When [buying neodymium magnets](https://buymagnets.com/shop/435/Neodymium-Magnets/Neodymium-Pot-Magnets/Neodymium-Pot-Magnets-BNA-Series-Countersunk/) you are typically given a “holding force” value of the magnet in pounds. They even have a [nice calculator](https://buymagnets.com/holding-force-calculator/) for determining holding strength given dimensions of the magnet.

There’s an assumption that the magnet is being attracted to a “sufficiently thick” steel base.

What I would like to know is how to use this information to calculate the repulsive force of a magnet. I haven’t been able to find a similar tool to help. Unlike with the holding force, I assume that another factor would be if you’re considering how much weight a magnet could lift a vanishingly small amount above the base or at what distance the weight could be held in equilibrium.

For example, what holding force would be necessary for a neodymium magnet to float 1” above a steel base if 1lb of weight is balanced on top of the magnet?

Finally, if the assumption of a steel base were replaced by another equal size magnet as the base, would that reduce the necessary holding force by 50% or is that calculation more complex?

Comment: https://www.kjmagnetics.com/blog.asp?p=magnets-vs-steel try this

Comment: @lorenzoBaldessarini Thanks for that. So, using a magnet for the base may not make much difference then, compared to a thick steel base.